# Is it possible to set a custom referer header in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, http, ionic-framework

I´m trying to set a custom Referer header for a Post-Request in Ionic, but so far I wasn´t able to since it doesn´t allow me to set the Referer header (by design in Browsers, I know).

Generally, I know how to set custom headers in a http request, just not how to set "unsafe" headers.

**So far I have tried:**

1. Normal post request with the Ionic HttpClientModule.
2. Post request with the Ionic Native Http module (which I honestly thought would work).
3. Using an HttpsRequestInterceptor service and adding additional headers there.

**Ways I can think of that might work:**

1. Creating a middleware which handles the request.
2. Making my own native plugin.

I really want to avoid these two options if at all possible. So, if you know of any other way how to do it, I´d really appreciate your help! Thanks!